# Create an animated plot of data points from csv

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, csv

I have a large CSV File containing some data points [~3MB, [example data](https://gist.github.com/Kartikay26/82d45ffda10e2b99f5d5)] as a series of coordinates.
I want to create an animated plot of point where the point is moving acoording to the given coordinates. What is the simplest way to do this?

I don't think excel can do this but maybe there is some way?

Comment: @Dave No, any way that works on windows is fine. Thanks for the HTML5 idea. I will try to use HTML5 Canvas to plot it

Comment: http://www.vbadventure.com/2011/11/animated-charts-in-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this JavaScript (JQuery) and HTML5. Since this isn't a programming website, I'll keep the response at a high level.

Use the FileUpload API to read in the CSV file, parse the data (free library such as [PappaParse](http://papaparse.com/) may help), and then use a charting library such as [Flotr2](http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/documentation) to show it. Flotr2 will allow this to be animated or you could keep redrawing the canvas.